# Xamarin Roadmap for dotnet core and netstandard

Tags: xamarin, .net-standard

I found a blog on this site [Xamarin netstandard Support](https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/) that is already 6 months old and makes no reference beyond Netstandard 1.6.
I similar question on the Xamarin Forums didnt get 1 view after 3 days.

**What is / where is the current roadmap for Xamarin on netstandard / dotnet core?**

Comment: NetStandard 2.0 is the goal for .NET Framework, .NET Core, and Xamarin, you can track the goals, additions and removals from 2.0 @ github.com/dotnet/standard The FAQ listed there provides the simplified answers, Mono already supports most of 2.0 since it and .Net Framework were the intersection points with Core needing the missing items. Per the Microsoft roadmap this is listed as `vNext`

Answer (score 1):

Don't think Xamarin publish formal roadmaps so that's why people can't answer you. If you're really keen you can track Alpha releases and follow the developer blogs where future insights are often published - https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/

Comment: I was coming to that conclusion Andy.  Even on the releases area it isnt easy to find such info.  Shame. Makes it hard to plan.

Comment: I suspect that .net / Roslyn / open sourcing has happening so fast that they're just playing catch up